# Zeroes of $f_n(x)=(x^2+1)^{\frac32}+nx-2$ make a monotone sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> $f_n(x)=(x^2+1)^{\frac32}+nx-2$
>
> 1) Prove that for every $n \in N $ there exist $x_n \in [0,2]$ such
>   that $f(x_n)=0$.
>
> 2) Show that $f_{n+1}(x_n)>0 $ and show that sequence {$x_n $}$_{n\in N}~
>   $ is monotone.

By using intermediate value theorem on $[0,2]$ i showed $x_n \in (0,2)$ exists.
I find the second part problematic. My attempt:

$$ f_{n+1}(x_n)=(x_n^2+1)^{\frac32}+(n+1)x_n-2=f_n(x_n)+x_n=x_n>0$$

Now the the monotone part :

Previously we got a relation: $x_n=f_{n+1}(x_n)$

$$x_{n+1}-x_n=f_{n+2}(x_{n+1})-f_{n+1}(x_n)=$$
$$(x_{n+1}^2+1)^{\frac32}+(n+2)x_{n+1}-2-(~(x_n^2+1)^{\frac32}+(n+1)x_n-2)=$$
$$\sqrt{(x_{n+1}^2+1)^3}-\sqrt{(x_{n}^2+1)^3}+n(x_{n+1}-x_n)+2x_n-x_n$$

This is useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already determined if $f_n$ are increasing.

Consider the following inequality

$f_{n+1}(x_n)>f_{n+1}(x_{n+1})$

and see what you can infer if you suppose $x_n\leq x_{n+1}$

Comment: I understand the answer except one thing,I never showed that $f_n$ is increasing ? Or i am not noticing it

Comment: In this case, you will have to show that the functions are increasing (even strictly) on [0,2].

Answer (score 1):

The function $f_{n+1}$ is strictly increasing on $[0,\infty)$, and all the $x_n$-s are by definition $\ge0$. Since $f_{n+1}(x_{n+1})=0$ and $f_{n+1}(x_n)=x_n\ge 0$, we have that $x_{n+1}\le x_n$. Also, since $f_{n+1}(0)\ne 0$, actually $f_{n+1}(x_n)\ne 0$ as well, and therefore $f(x_n)>f(x_{n+1})$. Thus $x_n>x_{n+1}$.

Comment: Why is it important if $f_{n+1}(0)\ne0$

Comment: Beause then $x_n\ne 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the following simple argument? $f_{n+1}(0)=-1<0$ and $f_{n+1}(x_n)>0$ so by the IVT, there exists $x_{n+1}\in (0,x_n)$ such that $f_{n+1}(x_{n+1})=0.$